# Безопасно ли оставлять FTP данные в файле обработчике AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

После sumbit формы, отправляется ajax запрос методом POST на страницу обработчик php, в обработчике происходит curl запрос по ftp, где нужно указывать логин пароль и сервер.Безопасно ли в файле обработчике писать код с данными к ftp?

Если проще, то можно как то получить доступ к php файлу через форму после ajax запроса, у файла стоит 644

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы "оформите" свой код. Но лучше для подобных вещей делать конфиг

Comment: Безопасно для чего? Если имеется в виду только приватность логина-пароля, то она не пострадает, если конечно обработчик только использует эти данные для запроса, а не выводит их). Если же говорить про безопасность в общем (в т.ч. от уязвимостей), то, как уже заметили выше, это зависит от конкретного оформления кода.

Comment: данные используются в запросе url_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,);

Comment: можно как то через форму добраться к этим данным?